# How do I create a table that has a varchar attribute derived from an integer?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So basically:

```
If integer from "NumberOfSomething" is between 5 and 10, then set varchar from "Quality" to "good"
```

5 < number < 10 = good

10 < number < 20 = excellent

Etc.
Would something like this be possible? If so, how would the create table statement look like? These 2 attributes would belong to the same table.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you can use a computed column (when writing this the database wasn't specified):

```
CREATE TABLE T 
(
    C INT NOT NULL
    ,Computed AS 
                CASE WHEN C < 10 then 'Good'
                ELSE 'BAD'
                END
)
```

This way if you have multiple queries that need that value, they can all get it from the table, and if the score changes, the computed values does automatically.

EDIT:

Here is an example on how to do it on MySQL also.  Note that this Generated Columns only work on MySQL 5.7.5 and above.

```
CREATE TABLE Test ( 
    Score INT,
    Cond VARCHAR(20) AS (
                CASE 
                    WHEN Score > 5 THEN 'good'
                    ELSE 'bad' 
                    END)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I want! However, I tried it in sqlfiddle.com and it outputs this when I try to run it:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS
                CASE WHEN C < 10 then 'Good'
                ELSE 'BAD'
    ' at line 4"

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: that one was for sql server, lemme convert the syntax to MySql

Comment: ok so the problem you're having is that SQL Fiddle only goes up to MySQL 5.6 and Generated Columns where added in 5.7.5 
http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/

Comment: I've set up a MySQL server (latest version), and now it says "Unrecognized data type. (near AS)" and "A comma or closing bracket was expected. (near CASE)"

Comment: I don't have a mysql server at work, I'll take a look at it when I get home

Comment: I just got it up on my machine with MySql on it.  I added an example of the syntax on how to do it on MySql also.